# The divergence theorem (Gauss) in 1 dimension: For me it is not clear how to compute the boundary integral!

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology

> > Gauss tells us that
> >     $$
> > \int_V \text{div}\vec{F}\, d^{(n)}V=\int_{S}\vec{F}\cdot\vec{\nu}\, d^{(n-1)}S,
> > $$
> >     where $S=\partial V$ and $\vec{\nu}$ is the outer normal.

For $n=1$, $V=[a,b]$ and $f\colon V\to\mathbb{R}$, this gives
$$
\int_a^b\frac{df}{dx}dx = \int_{S}f\cdot \nu d^{(0)}S,
$$
$S=\partial V=\left\{a,b\right\}$ and $\nu(a)=-1, \nu(b)=1$.

In nearly all literature it is said **without any reasoning** that
$$
\int_{S}f\cdot \nu d^{(0)}S=f(b)-f(a),
$$
i.e. we get the fundamental theorem of calculus.

I really wonder how we really can compute this integral, that is, how can we parametrize $S$ and what the meaning of the $0$-dimensional Lebesgue-measure could be.

To be more concrete:

Assume $S=\gamma(A)$ for some parametrization $\gamma$ (here $A$ has to be $0$-dim.), then we compute the integral over S by
$$
\int_A (f\cdot\nu)(\gamma(x))\sqrt{\text{det}(D\gamma(x)^T D\gamma(x))}\lambda^0 x
$$

*But*...

(1) What is a good parametrization $\gamma$? Maybe just the identity map $\text{id}\colon S\to S$?

(2) What is the 0-dimensional Lebesgue-measure $\lambda^0$?!

Comment: Do you know what are measures, or distributions ?

Comment: Yes, I know what measures are.

Comment: You should write [Gauss theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) as : for every bounded open $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth boundary, there exists a signed measure $\mu$ supported on $\partial V$ such that for every $f \in C^1( \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n) $ : $\int_V \text{div} F \ dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} F \, .\, d \mu$. When $n=1$, with $V = (a,b)$ it becomes what you wrote, and the measure is $\mu(E) = 1_{a \in E} - 1_{b \in E}$.

Comment: Hm, okay! But for me it would be more important to understand this without referring to measure theory, if possible. I would like to understand what I formulated is my questions (1), (2) and (3). In particular, I do not see how you get this measure.

Comment: I don't see what you mean, in my opinion it is just a matter of notation, and definition. The case $n=1$ is the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, and the case $n = k+1$ can be deduced form the case $n=k$.

Comment: Sorry, but what is unclear? My questions (1) to (3) are asking how to get $d^{(1)}V, d^{(0)}S$ and the integral over S.

Comment: Maybe something like $\int_{\partial_V} f \cdot \nu d\mu = \sum_{x\in \partial_V} f(x)\cdot \nu (x)1_{x}$?

Comment: Whoops, think the indicator function needs to be inside an integral

Comment: I think the question is: What is $d^{(0)}S$, i.e. the 0-dim. line element.

Comment: Maybe combine the normal and the differential element so it is +1 for those elements being integrated over that are in the positive direction and -1 for those elements in the negative direction. Isn't cell complexes something like this?

Comment: Right, I am thinking of cell complexes, chains and cochains and whatnot. I read about it in a book that has a site here http://www.discretephysics.org/ . There are probably tons of other things that the 0-dimensional derivative can mean aswell.

Comment: You have to start somewhere, and in this case one uses as a definition that the integral of $f$ over the boundary of an interval $[a,b]$ is $f(b)-f(a)$. You're looking at points, which are $0$-dimensional manifolds, and there one must make conventions.

Comment: And whats the convention for 0-dim. Lebesgue-measure?